# File create blocking UWP from loading

Tags: c#, xml, file, uwp

UWP is way over my head and sorry for this question.

Why is a file create blocking my UWP from loading?

```
public static async Task CreateFile()
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("sFile.xml");
    if (item == null)
    {
        StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sFile.xml");
        await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, GlobalVars.fileStrings);
    }
}
```

This function is called from my main method

The `CreateFile` function never returns. Why is that?

Edit: Added main method

```
public GroupedItemsPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    try
    {
        SampleDataSource.CreateFile().Wait();
        Debug.WriteLine("Continue");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = new MessageDialog(ex.StackTrace);
        Task.Run(async () => { await msg.ShowAsync(); }).Wait();
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
    GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Tick += SampleDataSource.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer_Tick;
    GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 120);
    GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: are you sure its never returning? isnt an exception occuring?

Comment: @DaveSmits added an example of my main method. No errors thrown.

Comment: When a call blocks indefinitely, break into the debugger, and look at the call stack. That will allow you to see, what the call is waiting for.

Comment: BTW this looks really bad: `Task.Run(async () => { await msg.ShowAsync(); }).Wait();`

Comment: i would recommend you never ever user wait method anymore .. that is killing in combination with await

Comment: @DaveSmits and how to call that async method within the sync main()?

Comment: just call it without await and make sure you do the exception handling. Or Make a async void method? or just the loaded event to do this kind of actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a deadlock. That's why you should never block on `async` code.

Instead of calling the async `CreateFile` method in the constructor of the `Page`, which is bad practice, you could call it once the page has been initialized by handling the `Loaded` event of the page. Then you can `await` the `async` methods as you should:

```
public sealed partial class GroupedItemsPage : Page
{
    public GroupedItemsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.Loaded += GroupedItemsPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void GroupedItemsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await SampleDataSource.CreateFile();
            Debug.WriteLine("Continue");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = new MessageDialog(ex.StackTrace);
            await msg.ShowAsync();
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
        GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Tick += SampleDataSource.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer_Tick;
        GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 120);
        GlobalVars.LastFreeSignalCheckTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but had some doubt, that's why I didn't even test it.
Well done sir.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the .Wait() from your SampleDataSource.CreateFile().Wait(); use await SampleDataSource.CreateFile(); instead.

Wait() is a blocking operation you must be careful if you want to use it because you can easy build a deadlock. In most situations await is the better choice.

In this case you are blocking the UI thread with your Wait() so that the successful execution of the CreateFile() method in the same thread is prevented. With an await instead your code should work because the thread is not blocked while you wait so that other code (like your CreateFile()) can be executed.

Another solution is to use Task.Run to execute the method in background so that you can wait with Wait() because the method is not executed in the same blocked thread (but it would still be ugly code design to block the whole UI thread).

Comment: I can't find a solution here though. It is a async call within a sync method. Task.Run is ugly call design and Wait() it blocking it. Then how am I supposed to call an async method within a sync method?